GUARDA ETH value - zero
I would like to clarify what happened in my GUARDA wallet. Is this some sort of scam? Or how can I get the right value for my 4.59 ETH?
Thank you for your advice.




Can you provide the address and transaction as text? What were you trying to do? What was the expected result and what you got instead?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc6264c832f1a741a4726dbfc03d2a283839446d5cee03539c77bd60bff5bc3a8

I was trying to withdraw funds from investing platform called InvestiRay, where I invested 6.25k(real money) and got to 10k, so I tried to withdraw funds to guarda crypto wallet - (they recommendet this wallet) from the platform before I would invest more. But I recieved to my wallet 4.59ETH with the value of 0,0 k..., furthermore the same time I got email with instructions that to create liquidity and that value of 10k for those 4.59ETH I have to add half of ETH from somewhere else to the crypto wallet.. Thank you.

Unfortunately it is a scam contract. The token is worthless. You have already lost the invested money. You should contact your local authorities that investigate online fraud.
